# Call to constexpr function accepting an array fails to compile

Tags: arrays, c++14, constexpr, non-type, template-variables

Consider this code:

```
#include <array>

template < int... Ints >
constexpr std::array<int,sizeof...(Ints)> theIntArray = {Ints...};

template < size_t NN >
constexpr void test(const std::array<int,NN>& xx)
{
    theIntArray<xx[0]>;
}

constexpr std::array<int,2> aa = {10,20};

int main()
{
    theIntArray<aa[0]>; // passes
    test(aa); // FAILS ?!

    return 0;
}
```

In the `main()` function the first line passes while the second line fails with a strange error message:

```
error: ‘* & xx’ is not a constant expression
note: in template argument for type ‘int’
```

I am using gcc-7.0.1 and you can find live example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+int...+Ints+%3E%0Aconstexpr+std::array%3Cint,sizeof...(Ints)%3E+theIntArray+%3D+%7BInts...%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+size_t+NN+%3E%0Aconstexpr+void+test(const+std::array%3Cint,NN%3E%26+xx)%0A%7B%0A++++theIntArray%3Cxx%5B0%5D%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconstexpr+std::array%3Cint,2%3E+aa+%3D+%7B10,20%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++theIntArray%3Caa%5B0%5D%3E%3B+//+passes%0A++++test(aa)%3B+//+FAILS%3F!!%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Is this according to the standard or it is a bug? What makes the second line fail while the first line passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `constexpr` functions must be valid with both a `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` arguments.  Or, in short, the arguments of a `constexpr` function are not `constexpr` within the body, but if they are `constexpr` outside the function body, certian calculations depending on them may be `constexpr` on return from the function.

```
theIntArray<xx[0]>;
```

this is only valid syntax if `xx[0]` is `constexpr`, but within the function body `xx` is **not** `constexpr`.

```
template < size_t NN, std::array<int,NN> const& xx >
constexpr void test()
{
  theIntArray<xx[0]>;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/809374d18bee6922).

Comment: TIL adding a const-reference to a literal type to mimic a user-defined non-type template parameter. upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that constexpr function parameter do not exist. That is, you cannot do

```
constexpr auto fun(int x) {
    constexpr y = x;
    return y;
}
```

and neither can you use a function parameter `xx[0]` as a non-type template-parameter inside the function. It's different for `aa[0]` because that is evaluated outside a function.

The only way to do what you want, is to make the function parameter a non-type template parameter. To do that, see the answer by @Yakk where he uses a const-reference to a `constexpr` array as a non-type template parameter.